# best practice for git hotfix from old tag

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I've recently started working on an open source project with git and have decided to work according to Vincent Driessen's [branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

I understand the reason behind this model and I've seen that it is widely recommended so it seems like a good choice.

What I'm missing in this model, and have failed to find online, is what it the recommended way in cases where a hotfix should be create for an old release (tag).

For example, my master contains the latest version - 2.0, and I have tags for versions 1.5 and 1.0. Now, say a customer who is working with version 1.0 found a bug in that version but does not wish to update to a newer version that contains the bug fix, and simply wants a hotfix\patch (not sure what is the correct terminology here). According to the model, this situation is not handled, and in the model a hot fix is fixed on a hotfix branch and then merged to the main lines (master\dev). But In my example the customer only wants the minimal set of commits which fix the bug without new features (as much as possible).

In this case, what should be the best approach git-wise? Should I create a dedicated branch from tag 1.0 and cherry-pick commits? should I branch from the first commit that fix the issue and revert back if it is easier? Should I keep this branch alive for ever?

I'm interested in knowing what to do in case where:

1. The bug is already fixed in a later version, for example somewhere between 1.5 and 2.0
2. This is a new bug and should also be merged to master.

References to best practices with different branching models are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. The bug is already fixed in a later version, for example somewhere between 1.5 and 2.0

If the development is following a reasonable flow (e.g.: retro-compatibility, incremental extensions, etc.) the  best solution for the user is to checkout the up-to-date version.

Otherwise, as you said, you should consider the opportunity to create a new branch from tag 1.0, cherry-pick the hotfix and then tag the branch as a subversion (1.0.1).

You should apply the same policy to the next commits, or at least to the next tags: suppose the hotfix to be released in the version 1.5, given the tag list [1.0, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5] you should create the subversions [1.0.1, 1.2.1, 1.3.1].

> 2. This is a new bug and should also be merged to master.

The hotfix is usually applied starting from the commit pointed by the HEAD of the master branch.

Rewriting history is not recommended since your project will be shared with someone else and there will be conflicts on synchronization's points (push/pull). Choose the most reasonable solution, but never patch a commit you shared with the community.

Answer (score -1):

Even this bug is found in version 1.0, but actually it’s new. No one can be sure the old versions have no bugs, so for the new find bug, you should fix it in the newest version. So for your situation, you should **fix the bug based on 2.0**.

Because `master` branch is the main code hosted on (or we call it production environment),  so you should solve the bug on `hotfixs` branch and then **merge it into `master` branch**. Then delete the old tag 2.0, and add tag 2.0 for the new merged commit.

Comment: Replacing tags for releases seems dangerous as nobody can tell which are the cascading effect of that fix, you don't want to redeploy 2.0 and have a different behaviour.